# fk pk relationship across rows

Tags: sql, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, split

When splitting a single table into multiple is it a common case that foreign key is referring to primary key from different row ?
for example
Source table data is

```
id1  id2 name1   name2
10   1   a10     b1
9    8   a11     b2
8    3   a12     b3
3    9   a14     b4
1    10  a15     b5
```

So when I create primary key table as

```
  create table pk_table (id1 integer primary key , name1 varchar2(20))
```

and foreign key table as

```
  create table fk_table (id2 integer, name2 varchar2(20) foreign key(id2) references pk_table(id1))
```

So when I split data as per tables :

pk_table data is :

```
id1 name1
10  a10
9   a11
8   a12
3   a14
1   a15
```

and foreign key data is

```
id2  name2
1   b1
8   b2
3   b3
9   b4
10  b5
```

So have you seen these cases where we do not have fk referring to same row pk in source table ?

**EDITED:** Updated table data to make it more valid.

Comment: Kindly read Korth's book "Database System Concepts". Also read whatever you find and understand on databases in the next couple of days. This is not a real question. Please be precise with what your problem is.

Comment: `1, b1` absolutely **should** exist in `fk_table`.  You have not transformed the records from the original table correctly if it doesn't exist.  What does `10, a10` link to if it doesn't?  Also, when creating table `fk_table`, you should still identify `id2` as primary key, as it is the primary key for that table.

Comment: If FK does not reference any PK then it is not FK itself.

Comment: @Rachcha : why it's not a real question ? Have you never seen such situation ?

Comment: @Santhosh: If FK does not reference any PK then we get referential integrity failure

Comment: @Peeyush From what I understood from your question, is that what you asked? From the data you provided, there seems to be no relation between ID1 and ID2, since there is a value in ID2 that's not in ID1. If ID2 is having values that's in ID1 then your question may be valid. That's what I think

Comment: @mcalex: 1, b1 can not come to fk_table as 1 does not exist as pk in pk_table. So it is discarded.

Comment: @Santhosh Updated question. Now have you seen these cases ?

Comment: But now you do have 1, b1 in the fk_table, so hasn't the question gone away?

Comment: @mcalex: No. Question is does it happen in when pk-fk are referring to different rows in source table ?

Comment: @Peeyush: No. I first determine the relationships between the elements in my database on paper and then actually create them in the database. I know which table is referencing which other table before I write up any queries.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly to answer the question you've asked:

Yes, you see data in different rows when you split up one table into two (or more). This is  how things are Supposed To Be™. It does not matter which row in the table the original data was, or the new data is.  The row number has **nothing** to do with your data, that is just how it displays itself.  For instance, you could have created the new `pk_table` like this:

```
id1 name1
1   a15
3   a14
8   a12
9   a11
10  a10
```

and it wouldn't make any difference.

Secondly, and this deals with what other people are trying to tell you.  The way you have transformed the original table into the two secondary tables **will not** give you a database.  The syntax you have supplied for the creation of the `fk_table` a) doesn't make sense, and b) won't work.

What you need to do when splitting up the tables is to create a new column in the `fk_table` that contains the primary key from the `pk_table`.  This extra column is the link that tells the database which record in `fk_table` matches which record in `pk_table`. Getting back to your original question, this link is the reason why it makes no difference which row the old records or the new records live on.  What matters is the foreign key column in the `fk_table`.

To make practical sense of this, the new tables should look a bit more like this:

pk_table - `id1` is the primary key:

```
id1 name1
10  a10
9   a11
8   a12
3   a14
1   a15
```

fk_table - `id2` is the primary key, `fk_id1` is the foreign key to `pk_table`:

```
id2  name2 fk_id1
1   b1     10
8   b2     9
3   b3     8
9   b4     3
10  b5     1
```

With this structure you can run queries that will correctly link each `pk_table` record to the correct `fk_table` record(s)

Answer (score 0):

The way you split the tables does not follow a normalisation criteria. There is no (visible) functional dependency between the fields in the source table. Secondly, your tables do not even share a a PK-FK relation. Your question is meaningless because your assumption that you split the tables with PK-FK is incorrect.

Comment: I am not normalizing my table. I am creating multiple tables from a single existing table. So the question is valid

Comment: My answer is correct. Clearly you don't understand PK-FK concepts, which is not a problem in itself, but your mind is closed to revise your (broken) assumptions. If you claim you are not normalising then you should not ask about missing PK-FK rows. If you want to progress, identify the PK in each table for starters.

Comment: @koriander +1 for being correct (and to knock out that undeserved downvote), but could I perhaps gently though with some irony suggest that clearly you don't understand how high level answers to obviously entry level questions might not result in satisfactiion from the querent's point of view?

Comment: thanks for the upvote @mcalex and for the kindness of your heads-up. I should have been as gentle to the poster :) Usually I try to reach the level of understanding of the poster but I had only time for a terse answer. That's why I actually upvoted your answer.